# Reading PCAP with Scapy without printing

Tags: python, scapy, pcap

I am reading a large pcap file using

```
packets = sniff(offline=pcapPath,
                     prn=customfunction, store=0, count=27242)
```

I want to avoid printing each packet to the console. How do you do this?

Comment: what is customfunction here?

Comment: it was just a function i created to block or allow packets through. like a mini firewall. @RossJacobs